# Как добавить переменные на текущий url?

Tags: php, html, url

Здравствуйте, у меня пара вопросов насчет переменных url.
 Есть страница с url `index.php?id=2`.

**Вопрос 1.** Как добавить к текущему url новую переменную, то есть сделать примерно так:
`index.php?sort=price` чтобы в итоге получилось `'index.php?id=2&sort=price`.

**Вопрос 2**. Можно ли это сделать без перезагрузки страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вопрос 1.**

Берем текущий URL добавляем нужную стоку:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$actual_link .= "&sort=price";
```

**Вопрос 2.**

при помощи php - нет. (но можно через Ajax)